# Get the PATH in htaccess using $_GET in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

Let's suppose that my site is example.com/pageone.

How can I rewrite my htaccess to get the **pageone** name using $_GET with PHP?

For example, in my code, I want to do something like this:

```
if($_GET['page'] === 'pageone' && file_exists('./pages/' . $_GET['page'] . '.php')) {
   require_once './pages/' . $_GET['page'] . '.php';
} else {
   require_once './pages/home.php';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for your case

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now you should be able to get page requested using `$_GET['page']`